# XeLaTeX resume coffin error

Tags: cv, xcoffins

I am trying to compile a resume template using XeLaTeX. I am getting the following error:

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}           
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} 
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages
\par{\centering
        {\Huge \textsc{Vinu V. Namboodiri}
    }\bigskip\par}
\section{Work Experience}
Some text here
\end{document}
```

The error that I am posting in the ERROR section disappears if I comment the following three lines in the code

```
%\usepackage{fontspec}                  %for loading fonts
%\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}  %other packages for formatting
%\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
```

ERROR:

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "vinu2.tex"
Startup Folder: F:\Vinu\Resume

This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(F:\Vinu\Resume\vinu2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\marvosym\marvosym.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3bootstrap.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3basics.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3expan.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3tl.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3seq.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3int.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3quark.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prg.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3clist.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3token.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prop.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3msg.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3file.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3skip.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3keys.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3fp.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3box.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\xcoffins\l3coffins
.sty" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"))

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> l_coffin_corners_\int_value:w 
                                         \c_empty_coffin _prop
l.188 \coffin_new:N \c_empty_coffin
```

I have updated [`l3kernel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), [`l3packages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3packages), etc., but no luck!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Vinu You should try to delete everything unnecessary from that code so that it becomes a *minimal* working example. It would be easier for us to help.

Comment: Updated the code section

Comment: If you select code in your post and click the button marked `{}` above the text field, code highlighting will be applied to it, as you see in my edit. (Blocks are indented by four spaces, inline code placed between backticks (`\``).

Comment: As an aside, you have introduced a spurious space with the line `{\Huge \textsc{Vinu V. Namboodiri}`.  You should add a `%`: `{\Huge \textsc{Vinu V. Namboodiri}%`.  (Unfortunately, I'm not MiKTeX user, so I can't help with the main problem...)

Comment: It works for me, you probably need t update your packages, howveer do not do this `{\centering
        {\Huge \textsc{Vinu V. Namboodiri}
    }`    You have a missing `%` and `\centering` and `\Huge` must always have the end of paragraph in scope ie the `\par` should be before both `}`

Comment: It works for me too on miktex 2.9. May be you should update.

Comment: In the most recent version it is `l__coffin_corners\__int_value:w` (the change happened several months ago). The `l3coffins.sty` package is now in `l3kernel` and not in `l3experimental` any more, like in your system.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved in later versions of l3coffins.